# What of the following can we conclude about a group with more than $12$ elements of order $13$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group containg more than 12 elements of order $13$; then which of the following is/are correct :

(A). $G$ is cyclic
(B). $G$ has a only one subgroup of order greater than $12$
(C). $G$ is never cyclic
(D). None of these

Comment: Suppose that $G$ was cyclic.  What does that mean?  Let $x$ be one of the elements of order $13$.  What is $\langle x\rangle$, the subgroup generated by $x$, i.e. $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,\dots\}$.  What is the order of $x^k$ for each $k\in\{1,\dots,12\}$?  If there was another element of order $13$ other than these, where could it be?  Does that make sense?  Why not?

Comment: How to check group is cyclic or not..

Comment: If you look up the definition, then that should be clear.  A cyclic group is one that can be generated by a single element.

Comment: How to check group is cyclic .explain by formulas  and theorems and what is lagrange's theorem?  Describe in detail..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

1) A finite cyclic group has **one, unique** subgroup (also cyclic, of course) of *any* order dividing the group's order

2) A group of order a prime $\;p\;$ contains exactly $\;\phi(p)=p-1\;$ elements of order $\;p\;$